# Create Greasemonkey script to Remove certain HTML lines when found

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make grease monkey script that could remove certain lines in html

like this for example

```
<ul class="actionList" id="actionList" style="height: 158px;">
    <li class="actionListItem minion minion-0 first">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="verbs">
                <a data-tipped="Look at the XXX" class="view verb tip-static" href="#"></a>
                <a title="Attack XXX" href="#" class="verb attack attack-1 action-attack-minion-2442 default"></a></div>
            <a data-tipped="minion" data-name="XXX" class="icon tip-static" href="#"></a>XXX</div></li>
    <li class="actionListItem minion minion-0">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="verbs">
                <a data-tipped="Look at XXX" class="view verb tip-static" href="#"></a>
                <a title="Attack XXX" href="#" class="verb attack attack-2 action-attack-minion-2442 default"></a></div>
            <a data-tipped="minion" data-name="XXX" class="icon tip-static" href="#"></a>XXX</div></li>
    <li class="actionListItem Minion Minion-0 last">
    <div class="header"><div class="verbs"><a data-tipped="Look at the XXX" class="view verb tip-static" href="#"></a><a title="Attack XXX" href="#" class="verb attack attack-3 action-attack-Minion-2442 default"></a></div><a data-tipped="Minion" data-name="XXX" class="icon tip-static" href="#"></a>XXX</div></li></ul>
```

I want to remove

tried something like this

$('li:contains("actionListItem minion minion-0")').parent().remove();

I'm still new in scripting its not working. Help would be appreciated

Comment: do you want to remove `class` or remove `li` ?

Comment: actually whole line  if I removed li wouldn't that remove class with it?

Comment: Yes remove li with it class. Check my answer with demo.

Comment: http://i62.tinypic.com/1yl65u.png  the li's marked with red square what I want to remove

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$( ".doc" ).remove()
```

and here's answer for your exact example ( http://pl.tinypic.com/view.php?pic=1yl65u&s=8 ):

`$('#actionList').empty();`

Comment: that's not working I don't want to remove every li under action list ul

Comment: u said  "the li's marked with red square what I want to remove". mark with red border want you really want to remove. U have many examples of removal by classes, by content in answers in this question. Try understand how does those functions works

Comment: yes there's some li doesn't show all the time in that HTML I just want to remove the ones contains creature in class  theres li  <li class="actionListItem player player"> I don't want to remove with creature

Comment: $( "#actionList .creature" ).remove()

Comment: tried this and this $('#actionList.actionListItem.creature.creature-0.first').remove();   didnt work :(

Comment: u should add space between id and class

Comment: still doesn't work ..

Answer (score 0):

```
$('li:contains("Vegetables")').parent().remove();
```

OR

If you know class name before delete line then simply do like

```
$(".doc").parent().remove();
```

```js
$('li:contains("Vegetables")').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="iconlist">
<li class="pdf"><a href="#">Milk</a></li>
<li class="text"><a href="#">Eggs</a></li>
<li class="htm"><a href="#">Cheese</a></li>
<li class="doc"><a href="#">Vegetables</a></li>
<li class="text"><a href="#">Fruit</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: actually there's mother <Li>  and this code removes all Li tree above the one wanted to be removed

Comment: Have you check my demo? Is it ok or need to change?

Comment: yes but actually the html build in the website I really want to do the script for  seems different than my example  this is how it looks like and the red square what I wanted to remove  i62.tinypic.com/1yl65u.png

Comment: Check my updated answer. `$(".doc").parent().remove();`

Comment: your script working for my example HTML but its not working on actual website I want to use it for ... check the image link